# Best way to round a number in javascript to a certain decimal places

Tags: javascript, math

I use this method to round numbers to decimals:

```
function roundTo(x, d) {
    var p = Math.pow(10, d || 0);

    return Math.round(x * p) / p;
}
```

But unfortunately cause of Javascript's floating point this will happen:

```
roundTo(23232323232323232, 15) -> 23232323232323230
```

What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: What is the result suppose to be?

Comment: @Musa 23232323232323232

Comment: Are you actually looking for decimal places? Or significant figures? Because your example doesn't have a decimal place.

Comment: @MattBurland Well, I am not looking for, I am wondering how to fix this incorrect behaivoir.

Comment: @Murplyx: Well then I don't know what you are asking then. That's how numbers work on computers. You will lose precision. To fix the problem use `.toFixed` although it's still unclear why you'd expect rounding `23232323232323232` to 15 decimal places to give you `23232323232323232` and not `23232323232323232.000000000000000`

Comment: @MattBurland Well, well, well. Because, I have a calculator, where you can select how many decimals the answer will have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function roundTo(x, d) {
    return x.toFixed(d);
}
```

Comment: What's the disadvantages of toFixed compared to writing my own function using regexes?

Comment: @Murplyx: What could possibly be the advantage to rolling your own versus using the functions that are built into the standard? The one that browsers can be optimized for.

Comment: I heard something of that there was a leak with toFixed

Comment: Not sure about a leak, but it has always worked for me. It is best not to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @Murplyx: Don't know where you heard that. A quick Google for "javascript tofixed memory leak" brings back no results to suggest any such thing.

Answer (score 1):

KJ Price's answer formed the basis, I wasnt happy with the string output.

If you want to have it output a Number and also handle String input, use the following:

```
function roundTo(x, d) {
    return Number(Number(x).toFixed(d));
}
```